# Ruby on Rails: Find all records that match a list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have 2 models:

```rb
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tags, dependent: :destroy
end

class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :item
end
```

My current query will return Items that have ANY of the tags in a list, I need it to only return Items that have ALL of the tags.

```rb
tag_list = ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz'] # may contain more

Item.distinct
  .joins(:tags)
  .where(tags: { name: tag_list })
```

What can I do to return only the Items that have ALL the Tag names from my list using ActiveRecord?

Thanks for the help.

Edit: I'm using postgres

Comment: What rdbms are you using? Postgres, MySQL?

Comment: are you sure the relationship gives you what you need? Each tag in your relationship has just one item. A typical item/tag relationship is a `has_and_belongs_to_many` so that a particular tag may be associated with multiple items, and you can (e.g.) get all items with tag.name = 'cool'.

Comment: @LesNightingill Very valid point. Sorry it is my bad attempt at making a simple, generic example. These are not my actual models and I'm not sure a refactor of the relations is an option for me right now.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
tag_list = ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz']

Item.distinct
  .joins(:tags)
  .where(tags: { name: tag_list })
  .group('tags.item_id')
  .having("COUNT(DISTINCT tags) = #{tag_list.size}")
```

Comment: Don't you have to add `items.id` to the group by as well? This will return any other item if it happens to have any of the tags in `tag_list` 3 times, e.g: having an item with exactly 3 Foo tags.

Comment: I think this is working as I needed but I've grouped by `'items.id'` instead, I was getting an error on the group by. Thank you, SQL is not my strength.

Answer (score 0):

Can we use `where("tags.name in (?)", tag_list)` ?

(If anyone has any suggestions, I would appreciate it)

```
Item.joins(:tags)
  .where("tags.name in (?)", tag_list).uniq
```

Comment: The IN operator won't ensure that there's a tag with the given name for every element in `tag_list`, so you might end up with items that can have only a "Foo" tag, or "Foo" and "Bar", etc, and in the best case if the item has the three tags then it'll return the expected item.

Answer (score -1):

You can filter all the tags having name 'Bar', 'Baz', 'Foo' (order matters) and group them by their item_id, then you can get the items with those ids;

```
Item.where(
  id: Tag
    .group(:item_id)
    .having("ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT name ORDER BY name) = ARRAY[?]::VARCHAR[]", ['Bar', 'Baz', 'Foo'])
    .select(:item_id)
)
```

Here the `ARRAY[?]::VARCHAR[]` is because tags.name is of type character varying, so you have to map the value to the right of the `=` in `HAVING` to whatever is the output of `ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT name ORDER BY name)`.